# Android NavigationUI Fragment in Fullscreen Mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-jetpack

I am exploring Google's Sunflower sample `Jetpack` app (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower). The NavGraph is defined in a navigation xml file that has a single `Activity` and numerous `Fragment`s.  The main `Activity` layout has an `AppBar` which is shared by all the fragments.  I would like to add another `Fragment` to the NavGraph that displays an image in Fullscreen mode.  The Android documentation shows the following code to enable Fullscreen mode:

```
 private fun hideSystemUI() {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

I call `hideSystemUI` in the new `Fragment`'s `onResume()`, and it is not working. The `Fragment` still shows the main `AppBar` and navigation that were set up in `MainActivity`. I've tried a variety of other solutions from S.O. threads, but most seem to be based on the standard `Activity/Fragment` pattern that I've had success with in my pre-Jetpack apps.  The new layout contains a `FrameLayout` with an `ImageView`. My new Fragment looks like this:

```
class FullScreenFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentFullscreenBinding>(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_fullscreen, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        hideSystemUI()
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {
                    activity!!.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to enable Fullscreen mode for one fragment?  I haven't changed Google's code at all, except to add the new `Fragment` to the NavGraph, but I can post additional code here if necessary.  I'm thinking that this may have to be managed through `MainActivity`, but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Fragment still shows the main AppBar and navigation that were set up in MainActivity.

Those are not part of the system UI, which is what `hideSystemUI()` is trying to control. If you want to hide widgets, update the `visibility` property (e.g., `findViewById(R.id.appbar).visibility = View.GONE`).

Comment: Works great!  To fix crash I used  `activity!!.appbar.visibility = View.GONE`